# Self join causing query to run forever

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, self-join, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to use a self join to get a cumulative sum. The problem is the query runs for more than 2hrs without any result. How can i fix this.

```
Select SUM(A.[GrossWeightKg] - A.[QtyLeftKg])/ 1000 AS DailyUsage
  , SUM(a.[GrossWeightKg] - a.[QtyLeftKg])/ 1000 AS Cumulative   
FROM [PMECentral].[dbo].[FactActualItemUsage] A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PMECentral].[dbo].[FactActualItemUsage] ff
        ON a.ActualItemUsageSourceId >= ff.ActualItemUsageSourceId
```

Comment: In sql-server 2012 you could use something like `SUM(a.[GrossWeightKg] - a.[QtyLeftKg]) OVER(ORDER BY ActualItemUsageSourceId  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT
ROW) ` without the self join

Comment: The expressions for DailyUsage and Cumulative are exactly the same. - That's an error, isn't it?

Comment: Are you missing an additional JOIN condition on an ItemId or something similar? The query as it is will produce a huge amount of output and, depending on the volume of data in the tables, will run for some time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That works wonders, much simpler and the query runs fast. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql-server 2012 you could use

```
....
SUM(a.[GrossWeightKg] - a.[QtyLeftKg]) OVER(ORDER BY ActualItemUsageSourceId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
....
```

without the self join. Look at the [`OVER`-clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.120).aspx)  especially the part with the `Rows`-clause.